# Creating an accordion through Javascript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, accordion

I am using Javascript, **with no jQuery**.

To the accordion title panel I've done this so far:

```js
var accordion = document.createElement('div');
            accordion.className = 'panel-group';
            accordion.id = 'accordion';
            document.getElementById('navgroupsframe').appendChild(accordion);

            var panel = document.createElement('div');
            panel.className = 'panel';
            panel.style.marginLeft = '-15px';
            accordion.appendChild(panel);

            var panelheading = document.createElement('div');
            panelheading.className = 'panel-heading';
            panel.appendChild(panelheading);

            var paneltitle = document.createElement('div');
            paneltitle.className = 'vgroupholder panel-title'
```

However, I want to get here:

```html
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                            <div class="panel" style="margin-left: -15px;">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <div class="vgroupholder panel-title" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#title1" onclick="removevBgs();">
```

How do I do this? (add `data-parent`, etc. with just Javascript, without jQuery).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider creating the parent element then injecting all the rest with a good old `innerHTML` since you're not using JQuery :)

```
var accordion = document.createElement('div');
accordion.className = 'panel-group';
accordion.id = 'accordion';

accordion.innerHTML = `<div class="panel" style="margin-left: -15px;">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <div class="vgroupholder panel-title" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#title1" onclick="removevBgs();"></div>
                             </div>
                       </div>`;

document.getElementById('navgroupsframe').appendChild(accordion);
```